# Android Java Efficient SQLite query with interruption

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, suspend

I have a table with > 200,000 rows (and might be a few million).

Sometimes the queries can take a few minutes to return a result.

I need to offer the end user the ability to abort the query and refine it.

To do that, I need to implement a query that can be cancelled or interrupted.

Is there a best practice for this?

The solution I came up with is to perform a series of smaller queries using LIMIT and OFFSET, checking for an interrupt between.

My concern is that repeatedly using LIMIT and OFFSET will result in searching the same data rows over and over, yielding a much slower query.  Or does SQLite recognize it can start the next query at the row number where a prior identical search stopped?

```
public class InterruptableQuery {

    public interface QueryResult {
        void queryResult(boolean interrupted, List<MyData> results);
    }
    private QueryResult queryCallBack;

    private volatile boolean _interrupted = false;
    private volatile boolean _cancelled = false;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public InterruptableQuery(SQLiteDatabase db, QueryResult qr) {
        this.db = db;
        queryCallBack = qr;
    }

    public void interruptQuery() { _interrupted = true; }
    public void cancelQuery() { _cancelled = true; }

    public void search(final String query) {
        Thread searchThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean done = false;
                int OFFSET = 100;
                int offset = 0;
                List<MyData> resultsList = new ArrayList<>();
                while (!done && !_cancelled && !_interrupted) {
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query + " LIMIT " + OFFSET + " OFFSET " + offset, null);
                    done = (cursor == null) || (cursor.getCount() < OFFSET);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                resultsList.add(new MyData(cursor));
                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                    offset += OFFSET;
                }
                if (!_cancelled)
                    queryCallBack.queryResult(_interrupted, resultsList);
            }
        };
        searchThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet the `rawQuery` is fast enough ... the problem is with iteration + creating model objects + adding it into arraylist ... If so then obviosuly you could interrupt only it ... another problem is that showing 200K elements in ListView/RecyclerView/AnyView doesn't make sens at all

Comment: I bet (again) that ListView + SimpleCursorAdapter + Loaders API + (optional but highly recommended ContentProvider) could handle this better than creating array of model objects (the only problem is fastscroll when CursorWindows refill really fast)

Comment: I'm not necessarily showing 200k elements in a ListView, plus I can break it up into multiple pages showing a 100 at a time.  The rawQuery isn't necessarily fast enough, especially if the query is convoluted.  Plus I am expecting a table of 2 million rows.

Comment: just use simple `rawQuery` and pass the returned `Cursor` to `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor, and no, no "pagination" with LIMIT / OFFSET

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear.  The queries can take a few minutes to run hence why the need to abort, so the user can refine their query if it is taking too long.

Comment: `"Or does SQLite recognize it can start the next query at the row number where a prior identical search stopped?"` https://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html#scrolling_window_queries

Comment: Thank you!  I'll edit my class to keep track of the row number of the last result, and resume the search at that point.  (can't do it now, but I'll post the fixed class later).

Comment: @jophul, did you got any solution??